# Transfomar colunas da tabela em JSON em Trigger do Postgres

Tags: json, postgresql, trigger

Estou criando uma trigger no Postgres e gostaria de transformar todas as colunas em JSON para inserir em uma unica coluna da tabela 'LOG', gostaria de transformar por exemplo 'OLD.*' em JSON e adiciona-lo na coluna 'oldvalue' da tabela LOG.

```
create table log_table (
    tablename varchar(200),
    oldvalue varchar(200),
    newvalue varchar(200),
    operation varchar(10),
    user_id integer
);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION teste_log() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
    BEGIN
        IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
            INSERT INTO log_table VALUES(TG_TABLE_NAME, TG_OP, user, OLD.*);
            RETURN OLD;
        ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
            INSERT INTO log_table VALUES(TG_TABLE_NAME, TG_OP, user, NEW.*);
            RETURN NEW;
        ELSIF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
            INSERT INTO log_table VALUES(TG_TABLE_NAME, TG_OP, user, NEW.*);
            RETURN NEW;
        END IF;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER teste_log
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON public.*
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE teste_log();
```

Answer (score 1):

Para executar essa ação você precisará utilizar a função **row_to_json**. Essa função irá transformar toda a linha (row) em um objeto json: a "key" será o nome da coluna e o "value" o valor do registro.

Na sua function você pode utilizar o código conforme abaixo:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION teste_log() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
        INSERT INTO log_table VALUES(TG_TABLE_NAME, TG_OP, user, row_to_json(OLD.*));
        RETURN OLD;
    ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
        INSERT INTO log_table VALUES(TG_TABLE_NAME, TG_OP, user, row_to_json(NEW.*));
        RETURN NEW;
    ELSIF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
        INSERT INTO log_table VALUES(TG_TABLE_NAME, TG_OP, user, row_to_json(NEW.*));
        RETURN NEW;
    END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Uma observação a respeito do json, utilize o tipo de campo **jsonb** (caso sua versão do postgres for mais antiga utilize o **json**) na sua tabela *log_table*, ele é otimizado e permite indexação do tipo GIN.

Espero ter ajudado :)